# Reload UIPreviewActions after 3D Touch peek

Tags: ios, 3dtouch

I have a tableView and on a 3D touch its cells display the View Controller behind it along with a UIPreviewAction that will share a URL that the "peeked" View Controller fetches.

The problem is that the server doesn't always come back with the URL before the UIPreviewActions are initialised and I don't want to give the option to share if the URL doesn't exist (certain pages don't have a URL).

Is there any way to reload the UIPreviewActions after the View Controller has loaded?